# How can I inject a dependency into the @Mock object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

There is a simple ModelMapper configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper mapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

There is a Mapper Utils class with a small business logic into which ModelMapper is injected:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MapperUtils {
    private final ModelMapper mapper;
}
```

Implemented a service that requires MapperUtils:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryService {
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final MapperUtils mapperUtils;
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CategoryServiceTests {
    @Mock
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Mock
    private MapperUtils mapperUtils;

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test my service using Mockito, but I don't quite understand how I can put another ModelMapper dependency in the MapperUtils object with the @Mock annotation for CategoryService with the @InjectMocks annotation

Comment: You can't, because it's a Mockito mock object. They don't have any fields.

Answer (score -1):

When using the @Mock annotation from a mocking framework like Mockito in a trying out environment, it's now not possible to inject a actual dependency directly into the @Mock object. The reason of mocking is to simulate the behavior of dependencies to isolate the unit beneath test. However, you may set up the mock object to go back unique values or behaviors as wanted on your test case.

Here's an instance of how you could use Mockito to installation behavior for a mocked item:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private MyDependency myDependency;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // Setting up a behavior for the mocked dependency
        Mockito.when(myDependency.someMethod()).thenReturn("Some value");

        // Your test code that uses the mocked dependency
        
    }
}
```

In the example above, MyDependency is being mocked the use of the `@Mock` annotation. The conduct of the someMethod of MyDependency is described using the Mockito.When and thenReturn methods. This allows you to specify what the method should go back whilst it is called in the course of the test execution.

If you need to check the interplay among the unit below take a look at and a real dependency, you may need to remember using the @InjectMocks annotation at the side of @Mock to mechanically inject the mocked dependencies into the unit beneath check. However, this technique does no longer permit for the injection of real dependencies into a mock.